# Removing subview from stackView places it at top of screen

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uistackview

When i remove an arranged subview from a stack view like so:

```
if userErrorLabel.isDescendant(of: stackView!) == true {
     stackView?.removeArrangedSubview(userErrorLabel)
}
```

it sends it to the top of the screen, not removing it and being really weird.

[image]

The red message in the status label.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try to do this

```
 userErrorLabel.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: I would prefer not to have to toggle the hidden property as that seems like the wrong way to do it. But for now this will have to do

Comment: Using `removeArrangedSubview` just removes the view from being having it's size and position managed by the UIStackView.  It will still be part of it's view hierarchy and therefore visible.  If you want to remove it permanently then us the `removeFromSuperview` method.  The `isHidden` property only needs to be used if you are hiding it and then will want to show it again.  The `layoutIfNeeded' should not need to be used here.  All of this is in the documentation if you need to look into it further.